# Should I use django-gunicorn integration or wsgi?

Tags: django, gunicorn, django-wsgi

I am setting up a web server with gunicorn + django.  There are two deployment options: either use regular WSGI, or use gunicorn's django-integration.  I'm tempted to use the latter, because it simplifies configuration, but the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/gunicorn/) says this:

```
If you are using Django 1.4 or newer, it’s highly recommended to simply run your
application with the WSGI interface using the gunicorn command as described above.
```

They give no explanation, so I wonder why it's "highly recommended" to go with WSGI?  Any ideas?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting with Django 1.4, your project will already have a wsgi.py, which can be used with any wsgi server (of which there are many, gunicorn being just one).

Essentially the old Django integration for gunicorn was just a convenience to get you up and running faster, but it's no longer necessary because all Django projects now have wsgi.py

Comment: Ok, thanks.  Just one thing: is there a performance difference between the two?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I wouldn't expect there to be.