# Why is gunicorn_django not recommended anymore?

Tags: django, gunicorn

We have an app deployed using gunicorn_django in production.  I've noticed that it's no longer recommended.  I'm wondering why it's not recommended, and whether we need to migrate to the newer way.

From https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/gunicorn/

> If you run Django 1.4 or newer, it’s highly recommended to simply run
>   your application with the WSGI interface using the gunicorn command.

Comment: It just says it's recommended to use WSGI interface, but not that gunicorn_django it's not. Actually they are pretty much the same.

Comment: @PepperoniPizza, according to the current situation with `gunicorn_django` you are wrong, see updated answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The essential part of `gunicorn_django`, `wsgi.py`, became integrated in Django itself.

To quote an [already existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15380460/should-i-use-django-gunicorn-integration-or-wsgi):

> Starting with Django 1.4, your project will already have a *`wsgi.py`*, which can be used with any wsgi server (of which there are many, gunicorn being just one).
>
> Essentially the old Django integration for `gunicorn` was just a convenience to get you up and running faster, but it's no longer necessary because all Django projects now have *`wsgi.py`*.

**UPDATE**

First of all, in Gunicorn 18.0 `gunicorn_django` [became deprecated](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/18.0/news.html#id1).

Second, since the first writing of this answer I have personally encountered obscure errors that
were specific to `gunicorn_django` in conjunction with `--settings` command line parameter (`gunicorn` command and `./manage.py runserver` worked fine).

Namely, the obscure import error *`application.some_model: 'field' has a relation with model another_application.AnotherModel, which has either not been installed or is abstract.`*

So, no, I would not recommend you using `gunicorn_django` in your new projects.