# Nginx responds with 502 error

Tags: django, nginx

While trying to deploy my app to Digital ocean I did everything according to this tutorial: [How To Deploy a Local Django App to a VPS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-deploy-a-local-django-app-to-a-vps).

While Gunicorn is working perfectly and `http://95.85.34.87:8001/` opens my app, Nginx, however, does not work, `http://95.85.34.87` or `http://95.85.34.87/static` causes a 502 error.

Nginx log says, that :

```
2014/04/19 02:43:52 [error] 896#0: *62 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 78.62.163.9, server: 95.85.34.87, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8001/", host: "95.85.34.87"
```

My nginx configuration file looks like this:

```
server { 
listen 80 default_server; 
listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; 
server_name 95.85.34.87;

access_log off;

location /static/ { 
alias /opt/myenv/static/; 
}

location / { 
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001; 
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name; 
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr; 
add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"'; 
}
```

In Django.settings I have `ALLOWED_HOSTS` set to `'[*]'`

Nginx is listening to port 80:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      894/nginx

tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      894/nginx
```

I think that the point is that Nginx does not point user to Gunicorn for some reason...

**EDIT:** I changed the `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;` line under `location /` to my servers IP address (instead of loccalhost) and everything worked. I am not sure if it's good decission or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the instructions tell you to use this to start Gunicorn:

```
$ gunicorn_django --bind yourdomainorip.com:8001
```

If you start it like this then Gunicorn will listen only on the interface that is bound to `yourdomainorip.com`. So it won't listen on the loopback interface and won't receive anything sent to `127.0.0.1`. Rather than changing nginx's configuration like you mention in your edit, you should do:

```
$ gunicorn_django --bind localhost:8001
```

This would cause Gunicorn to listen on the loopback. **This is preferable** because if you bind Gunicorn to an external interface people can access it without going through nginx.

With this setup the interaction between nginx and your Django app is like this:

1. nginx is the entry point for all HTTP requests. It listens on `95.85.34.87:80`.
2. When an request is made to a URL that should be forwarded to your application, nginx forwards it by connecting on `localhost:8001` (same as `127.0.0.1:8001`).
3. Your Django application is listening on `localhost:8001` to receive forwards from nginx.

By the way, `gunicorn_django` is [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16369354/why-is-gunicorn-django-not-recommended-anymore).

And another thing: don't set `ALLOWED_HOSTS` to serve all domains. If you do so you are opening yourself to cache poisoning.  Set it only to the list of domains that your Django project is meant to serve. See the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts) for details.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. You was right - the Nginx now serves my static files, but I didnt notice that I am unable to write anything into the server, I am getting the same "connection refused while connecting to upstream" error... Do you have any idea what might happen there?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "*write* anything into the server". The first thing I'd try is a `GET` query.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. Now I tried to make a request POST with data (via Ajax to one of my pages), but I am getting a connection refused error. Since Gunicorn is serving my App and there's no log entries regarding the POST error at nginx's error.log I assume that something is wrong with gunicorn. The get queries from Nginx works fine, because my static files are served... I will try to find out what  happens at the background when request POST is executed. I guess it is related to gunicorn somehow

Comment: When I suggested I `GET` I meant a `GET` that will be routed to Gunicorn. Gunicorn should have a log file somewhere. What do you see in it?

Comment: In Django admin 'Sites' settigns I had an old domain entry 'http://95.85.34.87:8001/' left so I tried to change it to my new domain 'http://lynxapp.io' and everything works now. I think that your answer to bind gunicorn to localhost solved the problem, thank you - now there is no "connection refused" error.

Comment: I surely have to read more about the 'localhost' thing, because I am not sure I fully understand how gunicorn can 'serve my app from localhost' though :)

Comment: I've updated my answer with an explanation of the interaction between nginx and Gunicorn. I've also added a note regarding `ALLOWED_HOSTS`. **You've opened a security hole while testing.** Please close it.